# Compare and Contrast: Artscroll and Koren Talmud Bavli

Tags: talmud-gemara, english, artscroll

I want to know why would someone choose Artscroll Talmud Bavli over the Koren Talmud Bavliand and vice versa.

What features do the Koren Talmud Bavli and the Artscroll Talmud Bavli and how do they compare.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I think that the only problem with your question is where you ask which is better; "better" is a subjective question that we try to avoid in stackexchange sites.  I like the idea of a straight compare and contrast -- people then can decide which is better for them.

Comment: Thank you and I will keep that in mind for the next time

Comment: I cant speak for the Koren which I dont possess but the artscroll is perfect. It is written by a collective group of scholars not just one man and I have yet to find a mistake.

Comment: Sy Koren and Sy Artscroll are written by a "collective group of scholars not just one man" so what makes Artscroll more perfect than Koren?

Comment: @preferred Do you work for them or something? Nothing is perfect.

Comment: @Double AA until I find many mistakes I consider it perfect. No I dont work for them but I appreciate what they have done. See my other post, it is only a pity that the yeshivot and kollelim dont and therefore end up wasting their time.

Comment: http://www.ou.org/jewish_action/04/2013/first-impressions-of-the-koren-talmud/  The names of the koren scholars are not well known rabbis like the artscroll ones. The metivta which he quotes is the best has many mistakes in their tosfos.

Comment: Me personally do not know anyone from the Artscroll team. And I do know someone from Koren, Rabbi Adin Steinsaltz. But popularity does not really affect anything. 

What Features Do you like about ArtScroll? That make it "perfect"

Comment: Price may also be a factor. (And how much space you have on your bookshelves.)

Comment: @Daniel put it as an answer

Comment: @user613 Ok. done.

Comment: @Ephraim They are about the same price (Koren is a little cheaper) (Koren is smaller than Artscroll) (could be true but most people who have enough room to fit Koren also have enough room to fit Artscroll even though there is a big difference since they take such big spaces)

Comment: @preferred there are many mistakes in artscroll - I found quite a few and they fixed them in newer editions (immediately in the iPad app, in the next printing for the printed edition). They are updating most *masechtot* a few times a year in the iPad edition

Comment: I learned all of Shas with artscroll but am doing this cycle with Koren which I also used before. From my perspective Koren is easier for a beginner, it takes you by the hand in a simpler way, is less intimidating, more modern in its layout and adds much helpful background, context and pictures. Artscroll is more academic, deeper in its footnotes for additional research but dryer and more intimidating. I didn't realize it at first but Koren's halakhic summaries on each page are quite helpful to understand the final halacha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally read a daf of Gemora with Artscroll and Koren. (Rosh Hashana 2) and even though it was very little I was reading different things on each one and I will conclude (mostly subjective)

- Koren has a little better literal translation and consistent translation (http://www.torahcafe.com/rabbi-tzvi-hersh-weinreb/the-story-behind-the-koren-talmud-video_314581457.html)
- Koren has **much** less explanation than ArtScroll
- Koren has a cool Halacha Column where it says the Final Halacha

So I would conclude that ArtScroll is more of a Learn-By-Yourself Gemorah

And Koren is more of a Reveiw Gemorah

Comment: (And according to that then ArtScroll is a (SUBJECTIVE) better gemorah than Koren and my reasoning is like this even though Koren is more of a Review Gemorah than ArtScroll, ArtScroll can still be a great review Gemorah. But on the other hand Koren, it serves as a great Review gemorah but lacks I feel on the explanation so is not so good. And it end up that Koren is a 6-Explanation (compared to ArtScroll) and a 10-Review and ArtScroll is a 7.5-Review and 10 Explanation (these numbers are very big estimate on my subject opinion)

Comment: Is the Koren one the Stienzaltz?

Comment: Yes is it english from Stienzaltz

Comment: This is a wiki add

Answer (score 7):

I have learned with both the Koren and the Artscroll. I actually switched to the Koren Steinsaltz. I have been using it everyday to learn daf yomi for 2 years. It really depends what your looking for if one is better than the other. As far as explanation, I would not label Koren a review Gemorah. While Artscroll is known for it's explanation, Koren has a lot of the explanation in the English translation of the running text as well as in the notes section. Diagrams and illustrations are brought in to clarify the text. It really depends on the page that you're on in any given tractate if there are more notes in the Artscroll or the Koren. I would reference Koren's version of Tractate Shekalim which has an abundance of explanation.

What I like best about the Koren Steinsaltz however is that you can follow in the flow of the discussion in the English translation which I find is very difficult with the Artscroll. However if you like to learn directly from the Tzuras HaDaf, Artscroll has it's advantages. You can go back and forth easier between the English and the actual page. Artscroll also has a good iPad app.

HZ

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, HZ!  Thanks for sharing your experience.  I hope to see you around.

Answer (score 0):

I have never learned with the Koren, but what I have heard is that it is basically just a literal translation of the Gemara text. So if you want the experience of learning the Gemara where you have to figure things out on your own the same way you would without a translation, the Koren seems to be best. But if you want to be able to get pshat right away, the Artscroll is probably best because it gives a lot of explanation.

Comment: This might be referring to older editions of the Steinsaltz translation - it is incorrect when referring to the new Koren Steinsaltz edition which, like artscroll, has commentary and explanations mixed into the translation