# What are the main differences between the Artscroll Siddur and the Koren Sacks Siddur?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, artscroll

Artscroll tends to be the status quo for many Jewish religious texts. I can't give a reason as to why that is, but Artscroll tends to be the standard in most Orthodox religious institutions. They make up the bulk of every collection within the various Shuls and centers I've been to.

That being said, I have seen a popular uprising with a book called the Koren Sacks Siddur. This is a recent release (around 2009) which has been pretty revolutionary in that it includes a series of new prayers for women (both for mothers after the birth of children and for fathers after the birth of their daughters) and also includes a series of prayers meant to be used within the State of Israel.

I was curious if anyone who has had experience with both books would be able to give me their feedback. Are they both considered equally valid and equally accessible to Jews looking to keep observance, or is one considered "more trusted" than the other?

Comment: Always better to trust a rabbi than any siddur.

Comment: @DoubleAA

I agree. I've asked my Rabbi the same question and he told me it was a matter of personal preference as both are considered trusted translations. 

I was just curious as to what other members of the community thought on the subject.

Comment: The layout differences are probably personal preference, but there are Nusach and instructional differences for which you should ask your rabbi for a ruling and not just follow any one Siddur.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40897/759

Comment: @TheSicilianJew While I dont think that this is a good question for the site, as it seems opinion based by nature, and everyone can have his own perspective, making it likely too broad, feel free to ask the question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), and you will likely receive useful thoughts.

Comment: You seem to have a different question in the title and the body. The title sounds on topic, but as @mevaqesh pointed out, the body doesn't. I would recommend making the body match the title here.

Comment: [This stylistically-similar question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35650/472) might provide inspiration for how to ask about this in a way that is less opinion-based.  I'd like to see this question be edited and reopened, as I'm curious about the differences too.

Comment: [This link](http://judaicahouse.net/koren_sacks_siddur.asp) answers the question in the title